# window.location changed in two different event handlers. How to halt execution or determine priority?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two different event handlers in two different locations in my page. One is supposed to be a default handler that handles 99% of the events everywhere in the whole site. The second is used on a single page to override that default behavior.

```js
$(function() {

  // side-wide default action
  $('#button').click(function() {
    window.location.reload();           
  });


  // handler used on a single page, somewhere else in the JS
  $('#button').click(function() {
    window.location.href = "/page2";   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="#button">Click</button>
```

No matter what I do, the first (i.e. `reload()`) operation is always called. I can put the `reload` in a `setTimeout` or I can completely refactor the JS so that it is either before or after the redirect assignment. It doesnt matter. The page is always reloaded and the URL never changes.

How can I get the redirect to work without gutting the default behavior? Can I set a priority? Can I halt execution after the assignment?

Comment: Can you just have one event handler and redirect to different page only if the source page is your second page where you want it to redirect to /page2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check whether you're on the page that needs the replacement click handler, and remove the old handler.

```
  // handler used on a single page, somewhere else in the JS
  if (this_is_the_special_page) {
      $('#button').off("click").click(function() {
        window.location.href = "/page2";   
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to handle this would be to add something like `data-skip-default="true"` to your button that you don't want to trigger the default action.

Then update your default handler to check to see if this data-skip-default is present and skip the reload if so.

Comment: I really like this idea! I'm already using data attributes on the button so this would fit in with existing patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are binding events to the same DOM element `#button`, both events will run one after the other and you can't even use `e.preventDefault()` or stop the event to bubble up as there is no event chain.

I'd suggest you then to find a way to identify the page some how (a cssClass in the body perhaps) and don't run the main function if you identify the page as a "don't reload page".

```
// side-wide default action
$('#button').click(function() {
    // if body class="prevent-reload", don't run your default function
    if (!$("body").hasClass("prevent-reload")) {
        window.location.reload();           
   }
});
```

You then could add a css class `prevent-reload` on that single page.